# Reduced promise returns early

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, reduce

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

function printDots(delays) {
    return delays.map((delay) => {
        return timeout(delay).then(() => process.stdout.write('.'))
    }).reduce((acc, prom) => acc.then(prom));
}

printDots([513, 3402, 1337, 4122]).then(() => process.stdout.write('DONE!'));
```

This prints `.DONE!...` but I expected that it would print `....DONE!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.then expects a function as it's arguments `(onFullfilled, onRejected)`, any value that is not a function is **totally** ignored

However, `prom` in the reduce callback is a promise, so only the first promise will be waited for

simple change, marked below should fix things

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

function printDots(delays) {
    return delays.map((delay) => {
        return timeout(delay).then(() => process.stdout.write('.'))
    }).reduce((acc, prom) => acc.then(() => prom));
    //                                ^^^^^^
}

printDots([513, 3402, 1337, 4122]).then(() => process.stdout.write('DONE!'));
```

Note, however, that the promises will all be commenced at about the same time, no waiting for 0 to end before 1 starts etc

given this, an arguably better solution for printDots is to use `Promise.all`

```
function printDots(delays) {
    return Promise.all(delays.map((delay) => timeout(delay).then(() => process.stdout.write('.'))));
}
```

> As per comments, the promises need to run sequentially - that's as simple as only using reduce

```
function timeout(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

function printDots(delays) {
    return delays.reduce((acc, delay) => acc.then(() => timeout(delay).then(() => process.stdout.write('.'))), Promise.resolve());
}

printDots([513, 3402, 1337, 4122]).then(() => process.stdout.write('DONE!'));
```

In this case, you need to provide an initial promise (Promise.resolve) to reduce so that the first iteration is working with a promise like all subsequent ones are

Comment: That worked, and the marking is a nice touch! Thanks.

Comment: a 6 character change in a single line can be hard to spot sometimes :p

Comment: @4castle - they resolve in the right order - the output will always be in time order - if you want to wait for A to end before **STARTING** B then the code needs to be different (not use map at all, just reduce) - the fact is, Promise.all is a better solution to this code as it is written

Comment: @4castle interesting, it gets run in parallel instead of in serial. I wanted them to be in serial, as you guessed.

Comment: I can answer that as well @BenAtkin

Comment: I figured out a way to [use both map and reduce](https://repl.it/Eq9z/2).

Comment: @BenAtkin - if you need to do that for "real world" code then yes, that looks cromulent :p

Comment: I like your reduce solution. AFAICT it's a solid implementation, simpler, and more efficient.

Comment: I know it's solid, I use it **a lot** - mainly for third party AJAX requests where the third party doesn't like being bombarded with multiple simultaneous requests :p